# frame is not showing the source at all

Tags: html, frame, frameset

Ok so I have the following frameset,

```
<frameset cols="30%,70%">

<frame src="left.html" />

<frameset rows="50%,50%">
<frame src="top.html" />
<frame src="bottom.html" />

</frameset>

</frameset>
```

but for some reason the files are not showing up!!! what am I doing wrong?!?!?! because I tested the code on http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_frame_mix  and it works perfectly fine!!!!

Comment: Do the files all exist and are in the same directory as the file specifying the framesets?  Is there anything in your web server error log?  If you run your page through an HTML validator, does it pass?

Comment: Make sure you have the correct `<!DOCTYPE>` set for your document

Comment: they all exist, if I check the source of the page on the browser and click on the links the pages are displayed properly

Comment: @Ken I have used `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: when I run it in an html validator I get like 7 errors about "Stray end tag frameset" and "Stray end tag frame"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem, I was placing it in the body, but it had to be placed under `<header>`